# How do I repair the lighting and heater in the cryo chamber?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I noticed that if you return to the cryo chamber you can camp there and repair stuff in it. I got all of the stuff required, but I can't repair it. If I click it in the recipe list it doesn't do anything. If I drag all the stuff into the crafting box, it doesn't do anything because I'm missing the panel or HVAC. I went to the camping screen and found the missing items in the building, but I can't get them out. I also dropped all of the other crafting items in too, and that didn't help.

[image]

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The menus in this game aren't very intuitive (yet), and this isn't explained very well.  Once you figure out how to get around the UI quirks, everything should make more sense.  Let's walk through this scenario:

---

First, open the **Camp** screen while standing on the **Cryo Facility**'s hex (click the button in the menu sidebar).

[image: Open the 'Camp' menu]

---

This recipe requires an object that cannot be removed from the camp (the electrical panel).  If you want to access the object to put in your crafting panel, you need to open the **Exam Room 17** camp.  Once you've visited a camp for the first time, you should see it at the top of the **Camp** screen any time you're standing on the hex.  Click one with the **Take** tool to select it.

*Note: Do not use the 'Consume' tool; you'll just eat all of your food or something.  And the 'Move' tool will just move the camp around rather than opening it.*

[image: Click on the Exam Room Camp with the 'Take' tool.]

---

Now that you can get at the Electrical Panel, all you need to do is move all of the ingredients listed in the recipe to the crafting panel.  If you had some ingredients in a container (backpack for example), you'll have to take them out first on the **Inventory** screen and drop them on the ground before you can move them to your crafting panel.

*Note: If a recipe says you need a particular skill trait (Electrical Systems in this case), **you actually need to put the skill trait in the recipe**.  You can find your skill traits at the bottom of the window.*

[image: Place all ingredients in the craft panel INCLUDING player skill traits]

And we're done. =]